# Regexp that matches not only consecutive duplicate words

Tags: regex

I need a regexp, which matches duplicate words. I try this:

```
\b(\w+)\s+\1\b
```

This good, but is matches only consecutive duplicate words.

How can i matches not only consecutive duplicate words?

Comment: use programming language

Answer (score 0):

Try matching `.*` in between occurrences:

```
\b(\w+).*\1\b
```

## Demo